# Which time zone to follow for lailatul qadr and others?

Tags: laylat-al-qadr

I don't understand  the timing concern of the lailatul qadr. Clerics say to pray on the odd numbered days of the last 10 days of ramadan. But different countries have different ramadan calendars. Our ramadan in Bangladesh may start a day later of that in Saudi Arabia. So, which time zone should we follow?

Comment: Follow your community and ALlah knows best. Following Saudi's isn't a good advice.